# How can you combine all lines that end with a backslash character?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

Using a common command line tool like sed or awk, is it possible to join all lines that end with a given character, like a backslash?

For example, given the file:

```
foo bar \
bash \
baz
dude \
happy
```

I would like to get this output:

```
foo bar bash baz
dude happy
```

Comment: Note that [it's in the `sed` FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.25)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

a shorter and simpler sed solution:

```
sed  '
: again
/\\$/ {
    N
    s/\\\n//
    t again
}
' textfile
```

or one-liner if using GNU `sed`:

```
sed ':x; /\\$/ { N; s/\\\n//; tx }' textfile
```

Comment: good one... I initally looked at this and couldn't understand it (so it wen't into the too-hard basket)... but after an in-depth look at Gilles' answer (which took quite along time) I had another look at your answer and it looked remarkably understandable I think I'm starting to understand `sed` :)...  You are appending each line directly to the pattern-space, and when a "normally-ended" line comes along, the entire pattern space falls through and auto prints (because there is no -n option)... neat ! .. +1

Comment: @fred: thanks I think I'm starting to understand sed too, it offers nice tools for multiline editing but how to mix-up them to get what you need is not straightforward nor readability is at top...

Comment: Beware of DOS line endings, aka. carriage returns or \r !

Answer (score 22):

It is possibly easiest with perl (since perl is like sed and awk, I hope it is acceptable to you):

```
perl -p -e 's/\\\n//'
```

Comment: short and simple, I like that one +1
And he didn't ask for sed or awk explicitely

Answer (score 21):

Here's an awk solution. If a line ends with a `\`, strip the backslash and print the line with no terminating newline; otherwise print the line with a terminating newline.

```
awk '{if (sub(/\\$/,"")) printf "%s", $0; else print $0}'
```

[It's also not too bad in sed, though awk is obviously more readable.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/how-can-you-combine-all-lines-that-end-with-a-backslash-character/13704#13704)

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer as such. It is a side issue about `sed`.

Specifically, I needed to take Gilles `sed` command apart piece by piece to understand it... I started writing some notes on it, and then thought it may be useful here to someone...

so here it is... Gilles' sed **script**  in **documented** format:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
#######################################
sed_dat="$HOME/ztest.dat"
while IFS= read -r line ;do echo "$line" ;done <<'END_DAT' >"$sed_dat"
foo bar \
bash \
baz
dude \
happy
yabba dabba 
doo
END_DAT

#######################################
sedexec="$HOME/ztest.sed"
while IFS= read -r line ;do echo "$line" ;done <<'END-SED' >"$sedexec"; \
sed  -nf "$sedexec" "$sed_dat"

  s/\\$//        # If a line has trailing '\', remove the '\'
                 #    
  t'Hold-append' # branch: Branch conditionally to the label 'Hold-append'
                 #         The condition is that a replacement was made.
                 #         The current pattern-space had a trailing '\' which  
                 #         was replaced, so branch to 'Hold-apend' and append 
                 #         the now-truncated line to the hold-space
                 #
                 # This branching occurs for each (successive) such line. 
                 #
                 # PS. The 't' command may be so named because it means 'on true' 
                 #     (I'm not sure about this, but the shoe fits)  
                 #
                 # Note: Appending to the hold-space introduces a leading '\n'   
                 #       delimiter for each appended line
                 #  
                 #   eg. compare the hex dump of the follow 4 example commands:  
                 #       'x' swaps the hold and patten spaces
                 #
                 #       echo -n "a" |sed -ne         'p' |xxd -p  ## 61 
                 #       echo -n "a" |sed -ne     'H;x;p' |xxd -p  ## 0a61
                 #       echo -n "a" |sed -ne   'H;H;x;p' |xxd -p  ## 0a610a61
                 #       echo -n "a" |sed -ne 'H;H;H;x;p' |xxd -p  ## 0a610a610a61

   # No replacement was made above, so the current pattern-space
   #   (input line) has a "normal" ending.

   x             # Swap the pattern-space (the just-read "normal" line)
                 #   with the hold-space. The hold-space holds the accumulation
                 #   of appended  "stripped-of-backslah" lines

   G             # The pattern-space now holds zero to many "stripped-of-backslah" lines
                 #   each of which has a preceding '\n'
                 # The 'G' command Gets the Hold-space and appends it to 
                 #   the pattern-space. This append action introduces another
                 #   '\n' delimiter to the pattern space. 

   s/\n//g       # Remove all '\n' newlines from the pattern-space

   p             # Print the pattern-space

   s/.*//        # Now we need to remove all data from the pattern-space
                 # This is done as a means to remove data from the hold-space 
                 #  (there is no way to directly remove data from the hold-space)

   x             # Swap the no-data pattern space with the hold-space
                 # This leaves the hold-space re-initialized to empty...
                 # The current pattern-space will be overwritten by the next line-read

   b             # Everything is ready for the next line-read. It is time to make 
                 # an unconditional branch  the to end of process for this line
                 #  ie. skip any remaining logic, read the next line and start the process again.

  :'Hold-append' # The ':' (colon) indicates a label.. 
                 # A label is the target of the 2 branch commands, 'b' and 't'
                 # A label can be a single letter (it is often 'a')
                 # Note;  'b' can be used without a label as seen in the previous command 

    H            # Append the pattern to the hold buffer
                 # The pattern is prefixed with a '\n' before it is appended

END-SED
#######
```

Comment: Neurino's solution is pretty simple actually. Speaking of mildly complicated sed, [this may interest you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930246/what-does-this-sed-expression-from-todo-sh-do).

Answer (score 2):

Yet another common command line tool would be `ed`, which by default modifies files in-place and therefore leaves file permissions unmodified (for more information on `ed` see [Editing files with the ed text editor from scripts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed))

```
str='
foo bar \
bash 1 \
bash 2 \
bash 3 \
bash 4 \
baz
dude \
happy
xxx
vvv 1 \
vvv 2 \
CCC
'

# We are using (1,$)g/re/command-list and (.,.+1)j to join lines ending with a '\'
# ?? repeats the last regex search.
# replace ',p' with 'wq' to edit files in-place
# (using Bash and FreeBSD ed on Mac OS X)
cat <<-'EOF' | ed -s <(printf '%s' "$str")
H
,g/\\$/s///\
.,.+1j\
??s///\
.,.+1j
,p
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that `read` in the shell will interpret backslashes when used without `-r`:

```
$ while IFS= read line; do printf '%s\n' "$line"; done <file
foo bar bash baz
dude happy
```

Note that this will also interpret any *other* backslash in the data.

Comment: Nope. It will not remove **all** backslash. Try with `a\\b\\\\\\\\\\\c`

Comment: @Isaac Ah, maybe I should have said "interpret any other backslash"?

Answer (score 1):

The Mac version based on @Giles solution would look like this

```
sed ':x
/\\$/{N; s|\\'$'\\n||; tx
}' textfile
```

Where the main difference is how newlines are represented, and combining any further into one line breaks it

Answer (score 1):

A simple(r) solution that loads the whole file in memory:

```
sed -z 's/\\\n//g' file                   # GNU sed 4.2.2+.
```

Or an still short one which works understanding (output) lines (GNU syntax):

```
sed ':x;/\\$/{N;bx};s/\\\n//g' file
```

On one line (POSIX syntax):

```
sed -e :x -e '/\\$/{N;bx' -e '}' -e 's/\\\n//g' file
```

Or use awk (if the file is too big to fit in memory):

```
awk '{a=sub(/\\$/,"");printf("%s%s",$0,a?"":RS)}' file
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use cpp, but it produces some empty lines where it merged the output, and some introduction which I remove with sed - maybe it can be done with cpp-flags and options as well:

```
echo 'foo bar \
bash \
baz
dude \
happy' | cpp | sed 's/# 1 .*//;/^$/d'
foo bar bash baz
dude happy
```

Comment: Are you sure `cpp` _is_ a solution? In your example the `echo` with string in double-quotes already outputs straightened text, so `cpp` is pointless. (This also applies to your `sed` code.) If you put the string in single-quotes, `cpp` just removes the backslashes but not concatenates the lines. (The concatenation with `cpp` would work if there would be no space before the backslashes, but then the separate words would be joined without separators.)

Comment: @manatwork: Outsch! :) I was astonished, that the sed command worked, but of course, it wasn't the sed command, but the bash itself interprets backslash-linebreak as continuation of the previous line.

Comment: Using `cpp` like that still not concatenates the lines for me. And the use of `sed` is definitely unnecessary. Use `cpp -P`: “`-P` Inhibit generation of linemarkers in the output from the preprocessor.” – man cpp

Comment: Your command doesn't work for me: `cpp: “-P: No such file or directory
cpp: warning: '-x c' after last input file has no effect
cpp: unrecognized option '-P:'
cpp: no input files` A `cpp --version` reveals `cpp (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3` - what? Ubuntu is patching cpp? Why? I would have expected to read GNU...

Comment: Interesting. Ubuntu's `cpp` indeed concatenates the lines and leaves some blanks. Even more interesting, the same version 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 here accepts `-P`. However it only eliminates the linemarkers, the empty lines remain.